# How can i get this page's content?

Tags: python, sockets, urllib

My code is:

```
import urllib
response = urllib.urlopen("https://namepal.com/").read()
print response
```

I want to get this page's content, but it throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/python27/tcl.py", line 3, in <module>
response = urllib.urlopen("https://namepal.com/").read()
  File "C:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 84, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 205, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 435, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "C:\python27\lib\httplib.py", line 951, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\python27\lib\httplib.py", line 811, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\python27\lib\httplib.py", line 773, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1158, in connect
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
  File "C:\python27\lib\ssl.py", line 372, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "C:\python27\lib\ssl.py", line 134, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\python27\lib\ssl.py", line 296, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10054]
```

So I use `socket` to get it, but it still fails:

```
import socket
import ssl

sock = ssl.wrap_socket(socket.socket())
#sock=socket.socket()
sock.connect(('namepal.com',80))
sock.sendall('GET  / HTTP/1.1\r\n'
             'Host: namepal.com\r\n'
             'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101  Firefox/32.0\r\n'
             'Connection: keep-alive\r\n'
             '\r\n')
response = sock.recv(4096)

print response
```

It throw a new Exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    sock.connect(('namepal.com',80))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 322, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 315, in _real_connect
    raise e
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:140770FC:SSL   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

I just want to get this page's content.

Comment: You first implementation works for me on Python 2.7.7. What is your Python version? I get error on your second implementation though!

Comment: Verified, same thing happens with `curl`

Comment: I think there's something funky with their SSL. I get "Connection reset by peer" with every method EXCEPT a browser (curl, urllib/urllib2 and httplib in Python 2 and 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSL protocols of https://namepal.com/ only support TLS 1.1/1.2 which is not supported by python2.7.7

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=namepal.com&hideResults=on
[Can I use TLS version 1.1 or 1.2 in python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606666/can-i-use-tls-version-1-1-or-1-2-in-python-2)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Python 3.3.2 or curl 7.21.4 (libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8z) either. Isn't TLS 1.1/1.2 support already in Python3?

Comment: @whereswalden according to https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html, "TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 come with openssl version 1.0.1.", so both python and curl doesn't works.