# python ftplib.error_perm: 500 Protocol not supported

Tags: python, sftp, ftplib

can someone point me in the right direction? i use this function to login to another **SFTP** site, but it wont work on this site. i receive the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USR01\python\py_programs\sftp_test1.py", line 87, in <module>
    main(site1, uid, pwd)
  File "C:\Users\USR01\python\py_programs\sftp_test1.py", line 83, in main
    sftp_login(site1, uid, pwd)
  File "C:\Users\USR01\python\py_programs\sftp_test1.py", line 55, in sftp_login
    ftps.login(uid,pwd)
  File "C:\Users\USR01\python\py_programs\ftplib.py", line 652, in login
    self.auth()
  File "C:\Users\USR01\python\py_programs\ftplib.py", line 660, in auth
    resp = self.voidcmd('AUTH TLS')
  File "C:\Users\USR01\python\py_programs\ftplib.py", line 254, in voidcmd
    return self.voidresp()
  File "C:\Users\USR01\python\py_programs\ftplib.py", line 229, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
  File "C:\Users\USR01\python\py_programs\ftplib.py", line 224, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 500 Protocol not supported.
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

this is a peice of my code:

```
import os, csv, datetime
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

def sftp_login(site1, uid, pwd):
    ftps = FTP_TLS(site1)
    ftps.login(uid,pwd)
    ftps.prot_p()
    ftps.retrlines('LIST')
    ftps.quit()
```

much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Probably the min cipher on the site is set to tsl1, and python 2.7 can't handle that :(

Comment: @RickyA can python 3 be a solution? if so, could i use the FTP_TLS module or is there an alternative module for python 3. i dont need to use python 2.7 (i am currently using python 2.7).

Comment: what version of the ftplib you are using?

Comment: 3 should be [good](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606666/can-i-use-tls-version-1-1-or-1-2-in-python-2) (if that is the problem of course)

Comment: i forgot to mention when i login manually to this sftp i have to accept an ssl cert. i think this may be this issue.., sorry i just logged in manually and remembered about the ssl cert..

Comment: @jes516, can you try passing the cert and see if this is ok? I think error 500 is referring to something else though

Comment: @Anzel i actually do not need a cert. it is filezilla that prompts me with the following message **before** connecting: `The servers host key is unknown. you have no guarantee that the server is the computer you think it is.` when i connect using `CMD` in windows, i do not get any certificate prompts. i login normally using USERID and PASSWORD.. i believe i can solve this issue using an SFTP module in python?

Comment: @jes516, see my answer. The reason why it prompts you for "servers hosts unknown" because your sftp server allows user/password login, if it sets to "key" only you will no longer have access unless you have a "key". Just think of it this way, ftps = ftp(secured), sftp = ssh(secured), they use different protocol to communicate

Comment: @Anzel i was reading the docs for pySftp this morning. i think that will do. part of the message i get from filezilla is: `Host: sftp1.testsite.com:22` `Fingerprint: ssh...`

Comment: @jes516, great! And I hope that helps you resolve the issue :)

Comment: @jes516, if you find my answer helpful and resolve your issue, please mark my answer as **accepted**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### updated:

After re-read OP question. You're trying to connect to **SFTP** which is a **SSH** connection whereas you are using `FTPS`.

So it shows your error that this Protocol isn't supported. and `ftplib` doesn't support `sftp`.

This module from pypi [pysftp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysftp) may help.

Comment: i need an sftp module in order to properly establish a connection with this sftp server?

Comment: @jes516, correct. **ftplib** does not support **sftp**.

Answer (score 0):

if it is active ftp,

try add:
ftp.set_pasv(False)

after the line:
ftps.login(uid,pwd)